# How to set z-index in draw2dTouch/Graphiti?

Tags: graphiti-js, draw2d-js

Ho can I set the z-index of any shape or element in draw2dTouch/Graphiti. Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right then you can not set the z-order explicity. BUT it results in the order you place the elements.